# What API response should I send when a consumer asks for a collection of resources related to a resource that doesn't exist?

Tags: api, rest, http

Let's say I have a resource

```
/providers/123
```

When a consumer sends a GET for that, it receives 200 OK and a record for the provider identified by 123, or a 404 Not Found if there is no provider with id 123. Fine.

Now let's say I have another resource

```
/providers/123/publications
```

which represents a collection of publications authored by provider 123. When a consumer sends a GET for that:

- If the provider exists and has some publications, they get 200 OK with the collection of publications.
- If the provider exists and has no publications, they get 200 OK with a collection that is empty.

But what if the provider doesn't exist? 404? 200 with empty set? 200 with empty set and a warning? Something else?

Comment: Also I should say I'm not looking for anyone to redesign the URI to be /publications?providerId=123, though I would also be interested in what people thinks the response should be for that if the provider doesn't exist (I think 200 OK with empty set).

Answer (score 2):

404 for sure. The URL refers to a resource that does not exist.

Don't give any more information than is required.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on your end user (the entity making the API calls)

If its a human being then 200 with an error saying that the provider doesnt exist seems the best. This case is applicable mostly with single calls to your API

If the end user is a robot parsing data from your resultset then 200 with an empty set will be a good choice.This case is applicable when API calls are made in bulk.

Example: This Geonames API gives country code from latitude and longitude, but if I have invalid latitude and longitude, it will throw an error message

http://api.geonames.org/countryCode?lat=181&lng=181&username=demo

Comment: One of the REST principals is to use the semantics of HTTP response codes - if a resource / parent resource is not available, return a corresponding return code (404 to be more concrete). 200 means OK. If a client relies on a 200 OK response with an empty content to think that this is caused due to a none-available parent-resource it might try to create a new parent-resource when actually only the content itself was empty. Therefore, return an error if there was one. Not considering proper status codes is layer 1 at max in Richardsons maturity model